# Magento 2 Migration URL Rewrite error CE

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, migration, data-migration-tool

I had migrated data of the Magento multi-store/multi-website from 1.9.3.9 to 2.3.3 but during migration, I'm getting below error for URL rewrite.

> [INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: Error
>   occurred. Rollback. [INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: Url
>   Rewrite Step]: Url Rewrite Step: rollback [INFO][mode: data][stage:
>   volume check][step: Url Rewrite Step]: Please fix errors and run
>   Migration Tool again

And because of this error when I hit URL of all products/categories or cms pages redirect to 404 pages.

If anyone faces a similar issue or knows any solution then let me know it'll be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am having the same problem :(
Did you ever get a solution?